# string index out of range even though it's not?

Tags: python

```
import json
dict = {"a": "1" , "b" : "2" , "c" : "3" , "d" : "4" , "e" : "5"}
s = json.dumps(dict)
print(len(s))
x = s.replace('"', '')
print(len(x))
l = len(x) - 2
print(x)
print(l)
for y in range (l) :
    if x[y] == ":" and x[y+1] == " " :
        x = x.replace(x[y+1] , "")
print(x)
x = x.replace("," ," ")
print(x)
```

len(x) is 30 and l is 28. so y+1 should be 29 max. thats still in the index. why does it give error saying it's out of index ?

Comment: `x = x.replace(x[y+1] , "")` you are modifiying a string while iterating.

Comment: @Ratery They're not, strings are immutable (except for ways not used here).

Comment: @KellyBundy Yes, you are right but in this case it's a reason of preblem.

Comment: @Ratery If it's not happening, it's not the problem.

Comment: @Ratery Btw also sounds odd that you're saying "while iterating". The iteration doesn't matter. And it's not like they're iterating the string, they're iterating a range. Your comment sounds like what people rightly say about certain trouble with *lists*.

Comment: @KellyBundy Yes, they're trying to iterate a range of indexes but assign new string to `x`.

Comment: @KellyBundy The iteration does matter. They're iterating over a range, but that range is being used to index a string. A string that they are changing the length of. I'm confused as to why you think this *isn't* a problem.

Comment: Side note, what is this code even trying to do? The loop repeatedly calls replace on `" "`, `x` doesn't even change after the first time this happens. The desired output is very confusing to me.

Comment: @BTables but the lenght of the string is getting smaller , so it shouldn't be out index.

Comment: @shriakhilc to delete the spaces between the " : " and the number.

Comment: @Polat the length of the string is getting smaller but the total range isn't. The range is based on the length at the start; i.e. the max length.

Comment: @BTables Well I think it's not really the iteration that matters. Like, I can cause an index error like that without the iteration.

Comment: @BTables Oh and about *"A string that they are changing the length of"*. Again: They're not, strings are immutable (except for ways not used here).

Comment: @shriakhilc Looks to me like they think `x.replace(x[y+1] , "")` works like *"Hey x, please replace your character at index y+1"*. I.e., what an imagined `x.replace(y+1, "")` might do.

Comment: So how do I fix that ? should I extract from l what ?

Comment: @KellyBundy `replace` doesn't do that, but `x = x.replace(x[y+1], "")` will certainly change the length of the variable `x`. New string is created sure, but the source of IndexError is still that line

Comment: @KellyBundy You can think that, but it is the iteration/modification that matters, objectively. I obviously understand strings are immutable. That still doesn't change the fact `x` is being reassigned to a *shorter* string. You can easily run this code yourself to verify.

Comment: @Polat If you want to know a fix, then say what you're trying to achieve, so we can tell you how to do that properly.

Comment: @BTables I know why the code doesn't work, I'm just saying the comments didn't describe it accurately.

Comment: I'm converting a dictionary to a string , then I want to remove the space between the  : and the number.
so instead of being a: 1 it would be a:1. and like that for all of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply replace all occurrences of ': ' with ':'

```
dict = {"a": "1" , "b" : "2" , "c" : "3" , "d" : "4" , "e" : "5"}
s = json.dumps(dict)
s = s.replace(": ", ":")
```